# Swagger - add static optional subpath segment in documentation

Tags: rest, swagger, endpoint

I try to document my api with swagger.
I have a base endpoint to `/api/quotes` that returns all the quotes in the collection and another to `api/quotes/random` where a single random quote is returned.

Not to confused anyone I also have the option to pass a query parameter `/api/quotes?random=true` to randomize the order of the collection. This one works as expected.

I have documented the first endpoint using jsDoc/yaml

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/quotes/:
 *   get:
 *     tags:
 *       - Greek mythological Quotes
 *     description: get mythological quotes
 *     produces:
 *       - application/json
 *     parameters:
 *       - name: random
 *         in: query
 *         description: "Optional param to randomize list order"
 *         type: boolean
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: list of all mythological quotes
 *         schema:
 *           $ref: '#/definitions/Quote'
 */
```

So far I have this.
How can I add my optional subpath /random within this documentation ?
How can I group theses endpoints in swagger ?
Is this restful ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually swagger did it automatically for me. I just added :

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /api/quotes/random:
 *   get:
 *     tags:
 *       - Greek mythological Quotes
 *     description: Fetch one random mythological quote
 *     produces:
 *       - application/json
 *     responses:
 *       200:
 *         description: One random mythological quote
 *         schema:
 *           $ref: '#/definitions/Quote'
 */
```

And swagger managed to group  the routes.
[image]

I still wonder if it is RESTFUL...